# Scapy is quiting after receiving packet

Tags: python, scapy

I tried to sniff some packets with scapy. I used this code from http://www.secdev.org

```
 sniff(filter="icmp and host 66.35.250.151", count=2)
```

(with an existing host, of course)
but when scapy receive the first packet, scapy quits by itself and nothing else happens. It returns to the standard terminal (as if I had typed in quit() )

I use:

```
Python 2.7.2
Mac 10.8.5
```

Comment: Is that all of the code you are running?

Comment: Yes. After the first packet scapy quits as if I had typed in quit()

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the example on the site you referenced it seems you need more code to view what was captured. Looking at the [demo page](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/demo.html) there are a few more calls going on;

```
>>>  sniff(filter="icmp and host 66.35.250.151", count=2)
<Sniffed: UDP:0 TCP:0 ICMP:2 Other:0>
>>>  a=_
>>>  a.nsummary()
0000 Ether / IP / ICMP 192.168.5.21 echo-request 0 / Raw
0001 Ether / IP / ICMP 192.168.5.21 echo-request 0 / Raw
>>>  a[1]
<Ether dst=00:ae:f3:52:aa:d1 src=00:02:15:37:a2:44 type=0x800 |<IP version=4L
 ihl=5L tos=0x0 len=84 id=0 flags=DF frag=0L ttl=64 proto=ICMP chksum=0x3831
 src=192.168.5.21 dst=66.35.250.151 options='' |<ICMP type=echo-request code=0
 chksum=0x6571 id=0x8745 seq=0x0 |<Raw load='B\xf7g\xda\x00\x07um\x08\t\n\x0b
 \x0c\r\x0e\x0f\x10\x11\x12\x13\x14\x15\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a\x1b\x1c\x1d
 \x1e\x1f !\x22#$%&\'()*+,-./01234567' |>>>>
>>> sniff(iface="wifi0", prn=lambda x: x.summary())
802.11 Management 8 ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff / 802.11 Beacon / Info SSID / Info Rates / Info DSset / Info TIM / Info 133
802.11 Management 4 ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff / 802.11 Probe Request / Info SSID / Info Rates
```

(this is a small snippet from the demo page itself for example only)

Comment: Thanks. But I cant run anything more after the first line, because it returns to the standard terminal, when scapy sniff the first packet. Even with count=1 or other arguments.